Is there a way to split a Google Document AI Document into it's pages
I've labeled 4 different documents for Google's Document AI, each with 15-30 pages. This means i've labeled about 100 pages on which I wanted to train a custom extractor. Now the extractor won't let me train because it needs a minimum of 10 train and 10 test documents (not pages).
The pages could be standalone documents in my use-case.
Is there a way to split the documents so that each labeled page of the document would become it's own document so that Document AI would let me train on this dataset?
I've looked at the structure of the Document JSON to see if there was a simple way of doing this with some code but I couldn't figure it out
